# Group SQL results by week and specify "week-ending" day

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to select data grouped by week, which I have working, but I need to be able to specify a different day as the last day of the week. I think something needs to go near `INTERVAL (6-weekday('datetime'))` but not sure. This kind of SQL is above my pay-grade ($0) :P

```
SELECT 
    sum(`value`) AS `sum`, 
    DATE(adddate(`datetime`, INTERVAL (6-weekday(`datetime`)) DAY)) AS `dt` 
FROM `values` 
WHERE id = '123' AND DATETIME BETWEEN '2010-04-22' AND '2010-10-22' 
GROUP BY `dt` 
ORDER BY `datetime`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`select
    sum(value) as sum,
    CASE WHEN (weekday(datetime)<=3) THEN date(datetime + INTERVAL (3-weekday(datetime)) DAY)
        ELSE date(datetime + INTERVAL (3+7-weekday(datetime)) DAY)
    END as dt
FROM values
WHERE id = '123' and DATETIME between '2010-04-22' AND '2010-10-22'
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY datetime`

This does look pretty evil but, this query will provide you with a sum of `value` grouped by a week ending on a Thursday (weekday() return of 3).

If you wish to change what day the end of the week is you just need to replace the 3's in the case statement, ie if you wanted Tuesday you would have it say

```
CASE WHEN (weekday(datetime)<=1) THEN date(datetime + INTERVAL (1-weekday(datetime)) DAY)
        ELSE date(datetime + INTERVAL (1+7-weekday(datetime)) DAY)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you using `CASE WHEN` instead of `IF`? Using `IF` I would write it as `IF(weekday(datetime)<=3, date(datetime + INTERVAL (3-weekday(datetime)) DAY), date(datetime + INTERVAL (3+7-weekday(datetime)) DAY)) AS dt` which is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that I like. This will return the date for the start of the week assuming the week ends Sunday and starts Monday.

```
DATE(`datetime`) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(`datetime`) AS `dt`
```

This can easily be adjusted to have a week ending on Thursday because Thursday is 3 days earlier than Sunday

```
DATE(`datetime`) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(`datetime` + INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS `dt`
```

this returns for the start of the week that starts on Friday and ends on Thursday.

You can group on this no problem. If you want to use get the end of the week based on the start you do this

```
DATE(`datetime`) - INTERVAL -6 + WEEKDAY(`datetime` + INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS `dt`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must choose between Sunday and Monday? When you can use DATE_FORMAT for grouping by string format of date, and use %v for grouping by Mondays and %v for grouping by Sundays.

```
SELECT 
    sum(`value`) AS `sum`, 
     DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'%v.%m.%Y') AS `dt` 
FROM `values` 
WHERE id = '123' AND DATETIME BETWEEN '2010-04-22' AND '2010-10-22' 
GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'%v.%m.%Y')
ORDER BY `datetime`
```

[How to use DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to group by any week ending day. Sometimes I may need to group by Thursday for example.

Answer (score -1):

I don't remember the exact math, but you can get WEEKDAY to wrap around on different days of the week by adding or subtracting days to its argument. You'll need to tinker with different values of *x* and *y* in the expression:

```
x-weekday(adddate(`datetime`, INTERVAL y DAY))
```

Comment: Have you dealt with these functions before? Any idea what the x and y values correspond to? I tried tinkering with it but feel like I'm shooting in the dark.

Comment: The value of ‘y‘ determines which day of the week will caue wrap-around and ‘x‘ provides a simple offset. The easiest way to figure out the right values is to construct a small table with sample dates and applying the above formula with different values until all the dates produce the expected results.